# How can I store order data into mySQL after user paying with paypal

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

I want to know that when my client will pay me via PayPal how I can I get it into my database I mean what code I need to write in PHP to get it.

Comment: Once user payment done, redirect PayPal page into your custom PHP page, there write your php and mysql code to insert into database

Comment: not sure how you are managing products & payments in your website, have a look https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/, it might help you.

Comment: But please take care. If you don't know how to programm such simple things, I'm not sure if you should handle paypal. Its quite risky and if you're doing something wrong, you can get into big troubles. I mean, we're talking about real money here.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/choose-integration-method/

Only select PHP into code sample, browse in sections and you can read all samples.